# How to calculate total days between two Persian dates (in yyyy/MM format)?

Tags: c#, date

I want to write a code in `C#` to calculate total days between two Persian dates while only year and month is given (for example: `1400/07`).
Totally I use the following code for calculating difference between two standard Persian dates:

```
string[] dArr1 = date1.Split('/');
            string[] dArr2 = date2.Split('/');

            PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
            DateTime d1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dArr1[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dArr1[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dArr1[2]), pc);
            DateTime d2 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dArr2[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dArr2[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dArr2[2]), pc);
            TimeSpan diff = d2.Subtract(d1);
            int dDiff = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalDays);
            return dDiff;
```

How can I find the difference for `yyyy/MM` format? I mean that only year and month is given and the code should consider first day of the month for first date and last day of the month for the second date.

Comment: You divide the days by 365 and the remainder by 12, rounding both down, to get years and months?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, Those dates are only inputs. I want to find total days based on this hypothesis that day of the first date is 1 and day of the second date is the last day of that month.

Comment: One way is to use Switch statement for determining days. But I think it is not correct. Because the last month of the year can be 29 or 30 days.

Comment: No idea what you want then. Show some example input and output.

Comment: @CodeCaster For example: difference between 1400/7 and 1400/8 is 60 days.

Comment: And what happens when you feed that to this code?

Comment: @CodeCaster I feed those two dates and expect to receive the answer of 60. The code should calculate 60.

Comment: What does it output now? What is the value of `dDiff`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this code:

```
 string[] dArr1 = date1.Split('/');
    string[] dArr2 = date2.Split('/');
    Calendar persian = new PersianCalendar();
    string lastMonthDays;

    int totalDays = persian.GetDaysInYear(Convert.ToInt32(dArr1[0]));
    string d1 = string.Format("{0}/01", date1);
    string d2;
    if (dArr2[1] == "12")
    {
        if (totalDays == 365)
        {
            d2 = string.Format("{0}/29", date2);
        }
        else
        {
            d2 = string.Format("{0}/30", date2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (dArr2[1] == "1" || dArr2[1] == "2" || dArr2[1] == "3" || dArr2[1] == "4" || dArr2[1] == "5" || dArr2[1] == "6")
        {
            d2 = string.Format("{0}/31", date2);
        }
        else
        {
            d2 = string.Format("{0}/30", date2);
        }
    }
    string[] dFinalArr1 = d1.Split('/');
    string[] dFinalArr2 = d2.Split('/');

    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
    DateTime dd1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dFinalArr1[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dFinalArr1[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dFinalArr1[2]), pc);
    DateTime dd2 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dFinalArr2[0]), Convert.ToInt32(dFinalArr2[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dFinalArr2[2]), pc);
    TimeSpan diff = dd2.Subtract(dd1);
    int dDiff = Convert.ToInt32(diff.TotalDays);
    return dDiff;
```